# How can a I scope the variable group to be only in a pipeline template?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am thinking of using [variables in a pipeline template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse)

1. I want the template to accept the `variable group name` as a parameter
2. When I load the variable group from the template, I do not want the values exposed back to the rest of the pipeline.

The purpose of the template I wanted to create was to take a variable and convert it to a file and store it as a Docker secret.

I am thinking I would need the [az pipelines variable group variable list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/variable-group/variable?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_pipelines_variable_group_variable_list) command to get the entry, but I can't find a parameter that tells me to show the value even if it is a secret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found a way to get secret values from CLI either but I cam with idea of limiting variable scope to specific job. You can pass variable group name as parameter and then use it in a job which is designed only for creating Docker secret:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: variableGroupName # name of the parameter; required
  type: string # data type of the parameter; required
  default: 'PROD'  
  
jobs:
- job: Ubuntu
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  variables:
  - group: ${{ parameters.variableGroupName }}
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo '$(armConnection)'
      echo '$(myhello)'
      echo '$(secretVar)'
    continueOnError: true
  - script: env | sort
```

and then

```yaml
jobs:
- template: jobs.yaml  # Template reference
  parameters:
    variableGroupName: 'my-variable-group'
```

`armConnection`, `myhello` and `secretVar` are secret from variable group. Is this is enough for you or you want to put all variables from group without writing them in yaml?

Comment: looks like what I would need, i can pass in the variable I want to extract. The only thing is that I have to adjust how my script works because I used step templates but you have it as a job here.